# How to set enum DTO object using enum VO object?

Tags: java, dto

How to convert one object to another? For example, I have 3 classes Car (equals to CarVO), CarDTO and CarFactory. The issue in that I can not set an object of CarDTO by an object of Car. Should I convert it to string or what? I would appreciate any help!

```
public class Car {
    private Long id;
    private String model;
    private Engine engine;
    private Integer manufacturedYear;

    private enum Engine {Petrol, Diesel, Gas}

    // Constructor, setters & getters

}

public class CarDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String model;
    private Engine engine;
    private Integer manufacturedYear;

    private enum Engine {Pertol, Diesel, Gas}

    // Constructor, setters & getters

}

public enum CarFactory {
    INSTANCE;

    CarFactory() {}

    public static CarFactory getInstance() {return INSTANCE;}

    public CarDTO createCarDTO(Car car) {
        CarDTO carDTO = new CarDTO();
        carDTO.setId(car.getId());
        carDTO.setModel(car.getModel());
        carDTO.setEngine(car.getEngine()); // Here is an issue 
        carDTO.setManufacturedYear(car.getManufacturedYear());
        return carDTO;
    }
}
```

Comment: You write a mapper that maps one to the other. Btw, you need the anum only once.

Comment: I have used ModelMapper to do the mapping. http://modelmapper.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CarDTO` and `Car` look like *data transfer object* and *model, e.g. with Hybernate annotations*. These classes lools mostly similar but cannot be uses one for the other.
To convert one to another you have several options:

- Create your own converters with copy all fields from one class to another
- [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/) is your friend! - use **MapStruct** that does the same but with much less code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the mapping between the different Engine enums in the factory method:

```
public CarDTO createCarDTO(Car car) {
    CarDTO carDTO = new CarDTO();
    carDTO.setId(car.getId());
    carDTO.setModel(car.getModel());
    switch (car.getEngine()) {
        case Diesel:
            carDTO.setEngine(CarDTO.Engine.Diesel);
        case Gas:
            carDTO.setEngine(CarDTO.Engine.Gas);
        case Petrol:
            carDTO.setEngine(CarDTO.Engine.Pertol);
    }
    carDTO.setManufacturedYear(car.getManufacturedYear());
    return carDTO;
}
```

Note that I had to change the visibility of the two Engine enums to package scope to do this.

A cleaner, more reusable way would be to write a separate method that converted the one `Engine` type to the other, and then use that in the factory method.

...and sure, you can certainly go the way of the other answers of bringing in a mapper library or something else that is more robust.  I just wanted to show you that what you were trying to do directly was doable.